# Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined while using custom cell-renderers in ag-grid

Tags: angular7, ag-grid, angular-router, ag-grid-angular

I'm using ag-grid to render a table in my angular 7.2.1 app. The custom cell renderer is just to render an edit button in the rows that will redirect to a different page.

I've done this before in a different app on a different Angular version a while ago, but for some reason the same code in this Angular 7 app is resulting in this. I think I may be missing something really simple.

I've created a minimalist reproduction of the error I'm seeing in this stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v98mjs

If you click on the Edit button, you will see this error in the console.

> ERROR Error: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined
>   ag-grid versions:-

I'm using the following version for ag-grid:-

> "ag-grid-angular": "^20.2.0", "ag-grid-community": "^20.2.0",

Please look at the stackblitz code in the link above for the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needed to define `onEdit` with [`Arrow Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this)

```
onEdit = (row): void => {
  console.log('row is being edited', {row})
    this.router.navigate(['/new-url', { id: row.incidentId }], {
        relativeTo: this.route.parent
    });
};
```

More example such thing: [ag-grid server side infinite scrolling accessing props](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55567203/1417185)

Have a look at the updated plunk: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oppxte

Without `arrow function`, inside `onEdit` function of `AppComponent` was not able to get reference of `this.router`, and hence, you were getting the error.

> Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined

I have also introduced `RootComponent` and `NewComponent` for better modularity in the example. Hope it will be clear with that.

Comment: Tricky issue to figure out without someone's help! Thanks, this worked :)